# How to post crash report from ACRA to google doc

Tags: android

Has anyone used ACRA bug reporting tool for android ? There is one option in which you can set google spreadsheet path so that u can get all crash reports in google docs without building backend ? Anyone knows way to do it ? Couldn't find this in documentation

Below is the link for ACRA

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-by-email

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Google Docs are deprectated as the Acra site says http://acra.ch/

I'm sending mine by e-mail to myself similarly to what they do in the example:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
                mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com",
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I find that is only the good way to get reports directly at mail id